# Django Populating New Project With Directories From Old

Tags: python, django, django-views, pipenv

New to Django and I created a project with Django 3.0 based on a tutorial, then created Project 2 based on a second tutorial, following the steps.

But when I use the command `django-admin startproject project2_project` it populates project2's folder with all of the directories/files from project 1, and everything else on my Desktop.

When I run the server, I get Project 1's website. Have looked in the Django docs and on here but can't  find any answers to this. Also, when I enter the virtual environment `pipenv shell` it says I am on my desktop: `(Desktop) bash-3.2$` This might have something to do with it?

Comment: What is the path from where you are creating your project?

Comment: ```/Users/xyz/Desktop/editdojo``` I was creating the project inside a folder of the same name, which is what the tutorial said to do. But when inside the folder, the pipenv shell command puts me on (Desktop).